# ionic slide box not working with ng repeat

Tags: ionic-framework

```
<ion-slide-box>
                  <ion-slide ng-repeat="item in data.slides">

                    </ion-slide>
 </ion-slide-box>
```

controller:

```
 $rootScope.data = {};
    $rootScope.data.slides = [
        {
            title : "Slide 1",
            data  : "Slide 1 Content",
            active: true
        },
        {
            title : "Slide 2",
            data  : "Slide 2 Content",
            active: true
        },
        {
            title : "Slide 3",
            data  : "Slide 3 Content",
            active: true
        }
    ];
$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
```

yet slide box is not working, I have added     `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();`

as well but it just does not work.How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you're working with angular js ...
i had the same problem and this way you can fix it ...

in your javascript code :

```html
function slidescontroller($rootScope)
{
$rootScope.data = {};
    $rootScope.data.slides = [
        {
            title : "Slide 1",
            data  : "Slide 1 Content",
            active: true
        },
        {
            title : "Slide 2",
            data  : "Slide 2 Content",
            active: true
        },
        {
            title : "Slide 3",
            data  : "Slide 3 Content",
            active: true
        }
    ];
$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
}
```

ok now you've got a controller ... then in your html

```html
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="slidescontroller">
<ion-slide-box>
                  <ion-slide ng-repeat="item in data.slides">

                    </ion-slide>
 </ion-slide-box>
  </div>
```

it's very important that your division tag should have the attribute called "ng-app"
good luck !

Comment: It is working with static data only, I have data coming from api and it does not work with it

Comment: ok then get the data from api and for example make a php page that recieves the data from api and writes the javascript code to the page ! you can even make data transfer with JSON !